# CRM Linq Query error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Anyone know why the following linq crm query is getting the error "Additional information: No from or join clause could be found for table alias p_0"

```
        var quoteProducts2= (from qd in serviceContext.QuoteDetailSet
                              join p in serviceContext.ProductSet
                                 on qd.ProductId.Id equals p.ProductId
                             where p.Name == "SP AusNet fee"
                              select qd).ToList();
```

Comment: Everything looks good from what I'm seeing.  Did you do anything different in the way you generated your early bound entities?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the CRM query builder.
I could reproduce this in 7.0.2.53 OnPremise, not in 7.1 Online, not in CRM 2013 or 2016. You can also reproduce this using advanced find in CRM - join the products and set a filter on the product name. Any other field (e.g. product id) is working fine.

Unfortunately by the time of writing this, there is no newer Version available for OnPremise Systems.